# Julia add indicator to candlestick chart

Tags: julia, candlestick-chart, technical-indicator

I'm new to Julia and I'm trying to add a technical indicator (let it be a simple moving average) to my candlestick chart. How should I do that?

```
using Plots, MarketData, TimeSeries
gr()

ta = yahoo(:GOOG, YahooOpt(period1 = now() - Month(1)))
display(plot(ta, seriestype= :candlestick))
readline()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general answer to your question is that `Plots` uses the bang (`!`) naming convention to naming functions which mutate an existing plot object. Therefore if you want to add something to another plot, you should call `plot!` (or `scatter!`, `bar!`, etc.) after your first plot call.

In your case, the high level solution would therefore be:

```
plot(ta, st = :candlestick)
plot!(my_indicator_data)
```

Now you're saying you want a moving average, so here's an example:

```
julia> plot(ta, st = :candlestick; xlabel = "Trading Day", ylabel = "Price", 
            xrot = 45, bottom_margin = 4Plots.mm)

julia> using RollingFunctions

julia> plot!(runmean(values((ta.High .+ ta.Low) ./ 2), 5)) # using mid-price
```

which will give you

[image]

you might want to double check that this is right, it looks to me like the average line is offset by one day, which might be down to some trickery `TimeSeries` is doing to the xticks.